# How can I block my code without using die statements?

Tags: php

Hi guys I am making a simple PHP API using McCock architecture-like structures, in my products controller I have a function to create a new product like this

```
public function create()
{
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

    $product = $this->model('Product');

    if (empty($data->name) || empty($data->co2_value)) {
        http_response_code(400);
        echo json_encode(
            array("message" => "Bad Request")
        );
        die();
    }
    //...
}
```

The  problem is:
If I only use `echo` to display messages at the end of a condition it does not stop the code from running like a `return` statement, but If I use return instead of echo, the code will display no messages

How can I solve this without using `die()` statements?

Thanks for helping out

Comment: Functions shouldn't be responsible for outputting content. You could return false or null when the product couldn't be created. Another solution would be to throw a (custom) exception and catch this exception in your controller

Comment: I assume that this function is very much incomplete? If you cannot create the new product, you could simply **not** return a new product. It's then up to the function caller to check if a new product could actually be created.

Comment: You can both echo and return: https://3v4l.org/9pGVa

Comment: @ChrisHaas of course you (syntactically) can, but that doesn't mean you should

Comment: @DarkBee, although I personally agree that that is general pattern that many of us would recommend, WordPress (yeah, I know), Symfony and even "PHP: The Right Way" use and/or encourage this pattern, so it isn't a blanket rule. For this very specific function, I would agree that it really feels like an unexpected side affect however. I wouldn't expect `create` to write to the response stream (or terminal output).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply `return` after the `echo`:

```
public function create()
{
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

    $product = $this->model('Product');

    if (empty($data->name) || empty($data->co2_value)) {
        http_response_code(400);
        echo json_encode(
            array("message" => "Bad Request")
        );
        return null;
    }
    //...
    return $product;
}
```

Basically if `create` returns a falsy value, then it failed, otherwise it succeeded. You could also decide to `throw` an `Exception` instead, like:

```
public function create()
{
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

    $product = $this->model('Product');

    if (empty($data->name) || empty($data->co2_value)) {
        http_response_code(400);
        throw new Exception(json_encode(
            array("message" => "Bad Request")
        ));
    }
    //...
    return $product;
}
```

Comment: Unsure why u would echo anything inside the function though. See my comment

Comment: @DarkBee I would not `echo` anything inside the function, but since the question referred to echoing inside a function specifically, an answer needs to explain the technicalities of that.

Comment: That's fair enough